# wp_head hook content showing up at top of RSS feed

Tags: rss, feed, wp-head

The RSS feed for a site I maintain recently stopped working. I did a little investigating and found that the `wp_head` hook contents of several plugins is getting injected at the top of the page, causing an XML parse error (obviously).

I'm really not sure what the problem is. I'm not really familiar with how WordPress generates its feeds, so I don't have much insight there. I recently upgraded the blog to 3.8, but the upgrade was done yesterday, and the guy who brought the issue to my attention made it sound like it had been going on for longer. I don't know for sure though, it certainly could be a 3.8 bug.

I've tried different themes, tried disabling plugins. When every plugin is disabled, the feed works, because nothing is hooking onto the `wp_head` hook that's causing the problem.

Comment: The wp_head hook is not normally called for feed generation, so you need to find which plugin or other piece of code is adding that to the feed. Also check that your WordPress core files have not been altered somehow.

Comment: Otto, if you'll post that as an answer I'll give you the bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wp_head hook is not normally called for feed generation, so you need to find which plugin or other piece of code is adding that to the feed. Also check that your WordPress core files have not been altered somehow.